# log4j file not trace nothing in JBOSS 7.1.1

Tags: spring, jboss, log4j

I create an spring application with log4j in JBoss 7.1.1.FINAL this is my configuration of log4j:

```
# Log4j level and names.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, fileAppender
# Log4j relative path.
dir=${myWebapp-instance-root}
file=WEB-INF/logs/app.log
target=${dir}/${file}
# Used only for development.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p (%F\:%L) \u2013 %m%n
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache=TRACE
# Log4j internal message debug , only on console .
log4j.debug=true
# File appender used in production.
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=${app.logdir}/app.log
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=${target}

log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=5

log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %t %p %c \u2013 %m%n
```

the directory and the file are created,but in app.log there is nothing in there(page in white)
Jboss not give any error running the application, this is the part of log4j:

```
17:01:33,342 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/projvehimerc]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initializing log4j from [/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/log4j-webapp.properties]
17:01:33,351 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, stdout, fileAppender].
17:01:33,352 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Level token is [INFO].
17:01:33,354 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Category root set to null
17:01:33,355 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
17:01:33,367 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
17:01:33,414 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) – %m%n].
17:01:33,416 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
17:01:33,417 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
17:01:33,418 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Parsing appender named "fileAppender".
17:01:33,421 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Parsing layout options for "fileAppender".
17:01:33,422 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} %t %p %c – %m%n].
17:01:33,423 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: End of parsing for "fileAppender".
17:01:33,429 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Setting property [file] to [/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war//WEB-INF/logs/app.log].
17:01:33,430 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [5].
17:01:33,430 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1MB].
17:01:33,431 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: setFile called: /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war//WEB-INF/logs/app.log, true
17:01:33,432 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: setFile ended
17:01:33,432 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Parsed "fileAppender" options.
17:01:33,433 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Parsing for [net.sf.ehcache] with value=[TRACE].
17:01:33,433 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Level token is [TRACE].
17:01:33,433 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Category net.sf.ehcache set to null
17:01:33,433 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.net.sf.ehcache=[null]
17:01:33,434 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) log4j: Finished configuring.
```

below

```
17:01:36,680 INFO  [stdout] (Finalizer) log4j: Finalizing appender named [stdout].
17:01:36,681 INFO  [stdout] (Finalizer) log4j: Finalizing appender named [fileAppender].
```

like I said the file is create but there is nothing, although the level is INFO, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're [excluding](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) the servers log4j library with a [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile). In JBoss AS 7.1.x you need to exclude the servers version of log4j. This should be fixed in 7.2.x though.

Comment: Thanks James...After 4 hours of struggling your answer helped me to get JBoss7 Logging working. Thanks a lot.