# Log4j stops working after random time/usage

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j, wildfly

I am struggling with this message:

> 15:34:47,323 INFO  [stdout] (Finalizer) log4j: Finalizing appender named [consoleAppender].

After about one hour of working on my project, happily viewing my app logs in Eclipse console, this message appears and console remains empty.

I can't find a reason for that: the project is running on Wildfly9, jdk1.8. My (minimal) log4j.xml file is the same which is working for another project!

```
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="target" value="System.out" />
        <param name="threshold" value="info" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I suppose there's some limitation, "cutting" my logs at a certain point. My question is: where?

### Edit

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>yyy.com</name>
    <description>yyy.com</description>
    <url>http://www.yyy.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
        <version.jboss.bom>10.0.0.CR4</version.jboss.bom>
        <version.javax.servlet.jstl>1.2</version.javax.servlet.jstl>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>        
        <version.compiler.plugin>2.3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.4.3</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.6</version.war.plugin>        
        <internal.repo>trew</internal.repo>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>xxx-maven-repo</id>
            <name>artifactory xxx</name>            
            <url>http://x.x.x.x:8081/artifactory/xxx-maven-repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxx-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${version.javax.servlet.jstl}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>redmond</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoip-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jglue.cdi-unit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-unit</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>        
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>            
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4j file not trace nothing in JBOSS 7.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307086/log4j-file-not-trace-nothing-in-jboss-7-1-1)

Comment: Well it is hard to say if it is really a duplicate, but how does your project structure look like

Comment: It's a typical Java ee 7 web application. What specific info do you need exactly?

Comment: do you package any logging-related libraries in your WAR?  (btw: JBoss AS was renamed to Wildfly, so JBoss-related question may still be relevant/helpful for Wildfly)

Comment: I attached my pom!

Comment: Not related to the topic really, but the servlet dependency should be `<scope>provided</scope>` not `runtime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `pom.xml`, there is the `slf4j-api` and `slf4j-log4j12`. When deploying to Wildfly, you don't need them as it adds logging dependencies implicity. You can either set `slf4j-api` to provided or exclude Wildfly's logging libraries as described in the linked question. You can also disable the automatic adding of Wildfly's logging libraries using `add-logging-api-dependencies` as described in [in Wildfly's documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Logging+Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and when I tried searching for a solution I ended up here. It was extremely annoying given that the logger could last few hours or few minutes and required a restart to restore logging capability.

Turns out that the solution provided here didn't help me, which is why I'm posting an alternative workaround.

What worked for me was simply to run the "standalone.bat" with administrative privileged.

It wasn't required before I "downgraded" from Windows 7 to Windows 10 Build 1709. It's safe to say that this issue is related to the Operating System and not the Wildfly or Log4j implementation.

I Hope this helps someone else!